# seekg invalid arguments?

Tags: c++, seekg

I'm trying to use seekg for the first time.
It says in the documentation it's arguments could be:

istream& seekg ( streampos pos );

istream& seekg ( streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir dir );

From what I understood, 'streampos pos' could be an int? I saw examples like "seekg(0)"
However when try to compile this it says I'm using invalid arguments:

```
void function(int pos){
ifstream reader("data.dat");
if(!reader.is_open())
    return 0;
int posinArchive = pos * 74;
reader.seekg(posinArchive);
```

I even tried to cast it to streampos directly:

```
  void function(int pos){
ifstream reader("data.dat");
if(!reader.is_open())
    return 0;
int posinArchive = pos * 74;
reader.seekg((streampos)posinArchive);
```

same thing.
seekg(0), nothing too.
What's wrong?

Comment: Post the text of the error you're getting?

Comment: invalid arguments'
    Candidates are:
    std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & seekg(?)
    std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & seekg(long long int, enum std::_los_Seekdir)

Comment: From the error, it almost sounds like the compiler isn't finding a declaration/overload for the first variant of the method that you have listed above (from the docs). I know it might be an odd question, but is there any chance your code can't access a definition for `streampos`?  Alternatively, it would be interesting to see if you'd have more luck with the other variant...

Comment: if I type seekg (0, ios::end); it does work.Also when I try to cast, streampos turns green so I think it knows what it is.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you have a workaround, then. To figure out what's really going on, you might consider running your source file through the preprocessor to confirm the `seekg` declarations are getting pulled in correctly from the header files you're including...

Answer (score 0):

The first version

```
stream& seekg ( streampos pos );
```

is supposed to be used when you want to seek to a position that you have previously got from a call to `tellg`.

If you want to seek to position 0, you have to use `seekg(0, ios::beg)` to get to zero offset from the beginning of the file.